# ionic react push to component transition issue

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic-react

I am developing an app with ionic/react and need to push to new component hence doing it by

```
this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/page/details',
        state: {data: {}}
    })
```

It does the job, but there is an issue with the transition. It appears like new component is loading and then push animation is happening with again loading the same component.

I can use routerLink with routerDirection as none, but not able to figure out a way to pass data with this approach.

Comment: Getting this bug too. Have you tried submitting an issue to Ionic?